# Share Outlook Calendar via API

Tags: outlook, calendar, ms-office, google-calendar-api, outlook-restapi

I need to share the main microsoft outlook calendar of my user with another Outlook user programatically, via an API.

I managed to integrate Oauth2 authorization with the correct scopes (`wl.calendars_update`) to access calendar.

Based on the [Outlook Calendar REST API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations) I could successfully retrieve the user's calendars from `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars`. But what we want is to share a calendar via an API. Is this possible?

For comparison google does this via [ACL](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl)s. And the code required for sharing is smth like this below:

```
const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${req.pre.user.microsoftAccessToken}` };
    const params = { scope: { type: 'user', value: google.calendar.mail }, role: 'freeBusyReader' };

    return rp.post(`${google.calendar.apiUrl}/primary/acl`, { json: true, body: params, headers })
      .then(() => res({ message: req.i18n.__('shareCalendarSuccess') }))
      .catch(err => res(normalizeErr(err)));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is impossible for now.

It seems Outlook.com REST API is very recent:

- [Microsoft introduces new unified Outlook APIs for Outlook.com & Office 365](https://mspoweruser.com/microsoft-introduces-new-unified-outlook-apis-for-outlook-com-office-365/) => Aug 12, 2015
- [Provide REST API support for outlook.com](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/9222078-outlook-com) => Microsoft answer: July 22, 2016

I need this feature too and I've written a feature request on Microsoft UserVoice: [Allow to modify calendars share/ACL/permissions using Outlook.com REST API](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/17671921-allow-to-modify-calendars-share-acl-permissions-us)